# Depurar una aplicación windows después de haberla instalado

Tags: visual-studio

Buenas,

La pregunta es:

¿es posible depurar una aplicación después de haberla instalado en el equipo?

En `visual studio` no hay ningún problema para depurar, pero al hacer el instalador e instalar la aplicación en el equipo no veo la forma de poder depurar dicha aplicación, he buscado si existe algo para poder ver los errores por consola o algo así pero no he encontrado mucha ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Cual es la intencion de depurar una vez instalada la aplicacion? Hay comportamientos distintos?

Comment: Efectivamente hay comportamientos distintos al probar la aplicación en visual studio y una vez instalada

Comment: No se si existe la verdad una manera de "depurar" una aplicacion ya instalada, pero te recomiendo que primero verifiques los errores, utilices try y catch para que la aplicacion no deje de funcionar y como es una apo destkop seria muy bueno que crearas un tipo de "reporte" donde cada vez que ocurre un error estos sean guardados en algun log local o en un servidor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Visual studio (si no es la versión express) en el menu `Debug` tiene una opción que es  `Attach to Process`, puedes usar esa opción para enlazar un proyecto en ejecución con tu código y así depurar.

Más info aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Para depurar externamente una aplicación:

1.- Abre tu solución de esa aplicación en Visual Studio.

2.- En tu proyecto dale click derecho y abre propiedades y ve a la pestaña Depurar

3.- Elige Programa externo de inicio y selecciona el ejecutable de tu instalación de la solución.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]